# Add auto to manual slider HTML5 - CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html, slider

I'm kindda new to HTML5 and I'm trying to make an slider that shows between 3 to 5 images, in auto mode as defect but that offers manual controls:

This is how it looks like:
[image]
Can someone help me? When auto, I would like that dots move according to the slide moment. Right now, this is what I got, and i took it from [another site](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`
<title>Banner</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>

<body>
<div align="center">
<br><br>TITLE<br><br>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:700px">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-left" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
<div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
<div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
}
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `setInterval` to set a interval that calls function `plusDivs()` after some specific time interval, something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>`
<title>Banner</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<style>
.mySlides {display:none;}
.w3-left, .w3-right, .w3-badge {cursor:pointer}
.w3-badge {height:13px;width:13px;padding:0}
</style>

<body>
<div align="center">
<br><br>TITLE<br><br>
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:700px">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-left" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
<img class="mySlides w3-animate-right" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
<div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle" style="width:100%">
<div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
<div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
<span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
}
for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
}
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " w3-white";
}

setInterval(function(){
    plusDivs(1);
}, 2000)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```